# The incomprehensible requirement of type matching in proto file

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, proto

I run some script, and the following error occurs:

> TypeError: 62 has type < type 'int' >, but expected one of: ( < type
>   'str' >, < type 'unicode' >)

The reason for the error is unclear. Running the script from the terminal - this error is issued. In the proto file, the field requested for the value 62 is **required uint32**. Where can be the problem?

I apply a full screen output:

[image]

There is here such function:

```
def get_patch_info(self):
        if self.mode == "manual":
            pi = patch_symbol.resolve(self.bf_old.elf, self.bf_new.elf)
        elif self.mode == "auto":
            raise Exception("Not implemented")
        else:
            print "Unknown patch mode: \"%s\"" % self.mode

        if not pi.func_jumps:
            raise Exception("No functions to patch")

        for fj in pi.func_jumps:
            if fj.func_size < MIN_FUNC_SIZE:
                raise Exception("Function '%s' size less than minimal: %d < %d" %
                            fj.name, fj.func_size, MIN_FUNC_SIZE)

        print "\n*************************************************"
        print "***************** Patch info ********************"
        print "*************************************************\n"

        pi.old_bid = get_build_id(self.bf_old.elf)
        pi.new_bid = get_build_id(self.bf_new.elf)

        pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]


        print "Header:"
        print "  Target BuildId: %s" % pi.old_bid
        print "  Patch BuildId : %s" % pi.new_bid
        print "  Architecture on which patch is built : %u" % pi.new_arch_type

        if self.patchfile:
            pi.new_path = self.bf_new.filename
            print "  Patch path    : %s" % pi.new_path

        self.pi = pi
```

There is such a proto file:

```
import "funcjump.proto";
import "markedsym.proto";
import "staticsym.proto";

message BinPatch {
    required string     old_bid     = 1;
    required string     new_bid     = 2;
    optional string     new_path    = 3;
    repeated FuncJump   func_jumps  = 4;
    repeated MarkedSym  manual_symbols  = 5;
    repeated StaticSym  static_symbols  = 6;
    repeated MarkedSym  global_symbols  = 7;
    required uint32     new_arch_type   = 8;
}
```

Accordingly, the error occurs on the line:

```
pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]
```

If I rewrite code with some modofications all works correctly. To do this, I have to follow next modifications:
1) I have to replace `required uint32 new_arch_type = 8;` on `required string new_arch_type = 8;` in proto;
2) I have to replace `pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE [self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]` on `pi.new_arch_type = self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine` in function `get_patch_info(self);`
So then everything works correctly. But this is working with strings. I need to work with numbers using enum. 
But if I work, according to the scenario described above (work with numbers using enum), the error above gets out.

Comment: I got tired of switching back and forth between the screenshot of the stack trace and the presented code. Please don't post code or stack traces as pictures.

Comment: Where is `ENUM_E_MACHINE` defined?  If its values are strings or `bytes`, then this is exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @Kevin ENUM_E_MACHINE is defined in this file
https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/blob/master/elftools/elf/enums.py
This is a part of large library named pyelftools. Before usage I have imported this file.
If try: print "  Architecture on which patch is built : %u" % ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine], it gives 62.
This result is exactly corresponds to EM_X86_64 in enum. This is what I need (the architecture of my computer is this). How I have said above, if I work with strings(I am not using enum to get numbers value from it), all works correctly.

Comment: @Kevin But if I work with number values, all crashed (my task is work with numbers values).
So line: "pi.new_arch_type = NUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]" gives us numerical value.
And in proto-file we expected number value, because of "required uint32 new_arch_type   = 8;"